# Can't understand the concept of URLs (possibly sharepoint specific)

Tags: url, sharepoint-2010, hosts

I've followed a guide that's instructed me to change the hosts file in sys32\drivers\etc in order to add a URL. This URL could've been 127.0.0.1 google.com - but it would then point to what instead of the google.com search engine on the internet? This was part of a sharepoint development training guide so I'm not sure if it's sharepoint specific.

Comment: The HOSTS file is not sharepoint specific, your example is a way of forcing a domain name to resolve to a different IP address than it would normally; http://accs-net.com/hosts/what_is_hosts.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! I would probably have marked this as correct if it were an answer. I'll give you a few minutes to post it if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it is not. If you write that in your hosts file, then when this url (google.com) will point to your own machine (127.0.0.1 = localhost).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So judging by the link Alex has posted to me - it's safe to say that any URLs mentioned in the hosts file will take priority over a URL that my ISP could typically resolve. That was were my confusion lied, but I think I get it now.